# Python 2.7 how to import and reimport

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I reload an imported file with python ?

```
def ClickOpenMyFile(self):
    import myfileinquestion
```

I want that unimport and import back if was already imported...

It is supposded to work ? No error but don't work for me

```
try:
    import myfile
except:
    reload(myfile)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module

Comment: It's not for reload if changed but reload in any case if was already loaded

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a real unload is not existing in Python. (as Vladimir already mentioned)

Assume you have a file foo.py with the following content:

```
NAME = "MyName"
def foo_funct():
    print "foo.foo_funct called", NAME
```

Importing and reloding works fine:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.foo_funct()
foo.foo_funct called MyName
>>> foo.NAME = "ANewName"
>>> foo.foo_funct()
foo.foo_funct called ANewName
>>> reload( foo )
<module 'foo' from 'foo.pyc'>
>>> foo.foo_funct()
foo.foo_funct called MyName
```

If I understood you right, this is what you want:

```
try:
    reload(foo)
except NameError:
    import foo
```

reload will fail with a NameError if foo is not already imported. So catch this one and execute a normal import then.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are plenty of similar questions. For example this one: [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

There is no general way to track any changes in already loaded modules; you might want to track any chages by your own. However there are some modules available that perform reload if source code was changed. In some cases [tornado.autoreload](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/autoreload.html) may be useful for you.